# Lazy loading problem with one to one mapping

Tags: java, jpa, foreign-keys, entity-relationship

I have 2 very simple POJOs and i have just one to one mapping between them.

1. contact.java
2. comment.java -- it has foreign key column to the contact.java

the code i have written is below.

### contact.java

```
@OneToOne(optional= false,cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="contact", fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@org.hibernate.annotations.LazyToOne(org.hibernate.annotations.LazyToOneOption.NO_PROXY)
private Comment mComment;
```

### comment.java

```
@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,cascade=CascadeType.ALL )
@JoinColumn(name="EW_CNTC_ID")
private Contact contact;
```

i am setting comment into contact pojo and finally i am saving contact.java

if i keep @OneToOne(optional= false, i am getting dataintegrityexception, constraintvoilationexception

if i changed @OneToOne(optional= true, then it is working.

i think that if optional is false, it is trying to insert contact, it find comment it is trying to insert comment, but it has reference to contact it has to set the foreign key without inserting contact it cannot keep foreign key .. 
if optional true the contact can be inserted without comment and PK generated for contact and tat is set in the foreign key column of the contact.--- anyway this issue is solved.

one more thing i am loading contacts i need to lazy load the comments, it is no where working can some one help on this, i strictly need lazy loading of comment because of performance problm.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am clearly telling to contact.java to lazily load comment, but why it is eagerly loading, i am not understanding...is this problem will be solved if i move my foreign key from comment.java to contact.java ? can some one help me on this...

Comment: Why do you set @org.hibernate.annotations.LazyToOne(org.hibernate.annotations.LazyToOneOption.NO_PROXY)
? This means you have to have cglib on the classpath.

Comment: I have cglib in the classpath, in some blog i read that we can do lazy loading with byte code manipulation and org.hibernate.annotations.LazyToOneOption.NO_PROXY this is the part of byte code manipulation, thats why i kept that annotation, is there any problem with that annotation?

Answer (score 0):

We have this issue in hibernate 3. Hibernate 4 fixed this issue.

If you want to load only contacts not comments then try like this(Imply change it to manytoone relation).

```
@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
private Comment mComment;
```